# Continue loop iteration after exception is thrown

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Let's say I have a code like this:

```
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (i == 2 || i == 4)
        {
            throw new Exception("Test " + i);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    errorLog.AppendLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Now, it's obvious that the execution will stop on `i==2`, but I want to make it finish the whole iteration so that in the `errorLog` has two entries (for `i==2` and `i==4`)
So, is it possible to continue the iteration even the exception is thrown ?

Comment: put the `try...catch` in the loop and use `continue`.

Comment: Be *exceptionally* careful of simply swallowing the exception and continuing. For starters, only catch the exception you know you can recover from.

Comment: Please view [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/213671) to understand why I have edited your title.

Comment: This is a very bad example you've provided to be honest... What scenario are you trying to solve by this?

Comment: @walther It's a fantastic example.  It's a short but complete program capable of reproducing the problematic behavior described.  It's greatly superior to some large block of code for which 95% of it is unrelated to the question.  I'm quite *thankful* that the OP took the time to create a short working example.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Just change the scope of the `catch` to be inside the loop, not outside it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    try
    {
        if (i == 2 || i == 4)
        {
            throw new Exception("Test " + i);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorLog.AppendLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Why do you throw the exception at all?
You could just write to the log immediately:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (i == 2 || i == 4)
    {
        errorLog.AppendLine(ex.Message);
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe his actual use case is quite this trivial. Presumably, this is mere sample code to demonstrate the control flow requirement.

Comment: @user414076 Even so, Kenneth brings up a valuable point.  Worst case, call an external method to write the log OR perhaps add the exception to a list of exceptions and write after the loop.  Point is, there are other ways to skin this cat

Comment: Well, if he posts his actual use case, I could adapt my answer. The point is that you shouldn't put a try catch when the method itself raises the exception. I would only do that to catch exceptions from other calls. If I throw an exception I want it to travel up the stack.

Comment: @DavidL, adding to a list of exceptions means still needing to solve the question, namely, *completing the loop.* And Kenneth, I simply would not assume the exception is being explicitly thrown here. Rethink the loop body to be `SomePossiblyExceptionalCode();` if it helps.

Comment: @user414076 Agreed, but at least it's consistent with logging the error in the loop.  Kenneth's point is that it should bubble up and I agree.  Given the context of the scenario that's been presented, no reason to throw.

Comment: @Kenneth That's still assuming the method itself is what raises the exception.  My guess is that's not the case, he simply did that here as it's the easiest way of creating a minimal repro.

Comment: @servy OK, but if it's not the method itself which raises the exception, it changes the question. I can't base my answer on assumptions. What I say here, is completely valid based on what's there. If it's thrown inside another method he should simply move the try/catch in the loop (which you already mentioned). I just wanted to point out that if this is his use case, not throwing and catching might be a better solution.

Comment: @Kenneth No, it doesn't change the question at all.  The question is, "is it possible to continue the iteration even the exception is thrown?".  The code is just one example, but the question is asking for the general case, not just for that one exact code snippet.  Even looking at the code it's pretty clear that it's just for demonstration purposes. If it was the *actual* code he was using I'd tell him not to use a loop at all and instead replace the whole block with `errorLog.AppendLine("Test 2\nTest4");` but as I know that's not his *real* code I wouldn't put that in an answer.

Comment: OK. What I'm saying is, your answer is certainly valid and the most generic case. What I added was a special case which could be valid as well, depending on his situation. I still think it adds to overall view.